# I installed Lubuntu but the system shows im running Ubuntu. is this correct?

Tags: lubuntu

i am brand new , have mercy

installed lubuntu on an old 2005 toshiba 32bit pentium M laptop with 1.5G ram , during install , I asnwered yes to
'update to latest s/w '  . now the 'hardinfo' app shows im running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

1. does that make sense?
2. is there an easy way to confirm which DE (desktop) i am running? im surprised 'hardinfo' doesnt want to tell me that

btw- the performance seems to be ok.

thx

Comment: I'm a Lubuntu user, and I consider my system a Ubuntu one. The base of our systems is a Ubuntu base; where Lubuntu being a [*flavor* of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) use that base and replace only parts of Ubuntu Desktop with other parts; Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop, `openbox` as the WM & Qt5 as the core libraries/toolkits (which differs to Ubuntu Desktop which uses GNOME Desktop, GTK3 libs/tk etc.  You're using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which has *standard* support until April 2023 (which is very close so please note it!).  You're using the LXDE desktop which is now *deprecated*

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: FYI: To get answers you appear to be after you could use `neofetch`, a quick glance at the manifest of the Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS ISO (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.manifest) shows it there..   Your system as I see it is now Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (with LXDE), and I still have one IBM thinkpad using pentium M with 18.04 installed; but I'll likley move that to Debian within two months due to EOSS of 18.04 & EOL of *i386*  (Debian & Ubuntu refer to all grades of 32-bit x86 as *i386*; your cpu will be *i686* class though to the linux kernel)

Comment: If you haven't worked it out, there is no upgrade path to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, as it was the last Ubuntu release that used the now *deprecated* LXDE desktop, with LXDE using the *deprecated* GTK2 libraries/toolkit. The LXDE *devs* wrote about the port of LXDE to GTK3 (*which is heavier*) and instead ported to Qt5 joining with the Razor-Qt *devs* creating the replacement LXQt desktop that Lubuntu from 18.10 & up uses.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.10 was released in *i386* (32-bit), with ISOs also produced of 19.04 (*Lubuntu & Xubuntu alone got this far*), but 19.04 was the end of the road for *i386* support & because 18.10/19.04 were not LTS releases, 18.04 LTS lived longer (3 years for *flavors* with EOSS or end of standard support at 5 years meaning April 2023).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct.

I'm a Lubuntu user, and I consider my system a Ubuntu one. The base of our systems is a Ubuntu base; where Lubuntu being a [flavor of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) use that base and replace only parts of Ubuntu Desktop with other parts; Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop, `openbox` as the WM & Qt5 as the core libraries/toolkits (which differs to Ubuntu Desktop which uses GNOME Desktop, GTK3 libs/tk etc. You're using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which has standard support until **April 2023** (*which is very close so please note it!*). You're using the **LXDE** desktop which is now *deprecated*

FYI: To get answers you appear to be after you could use neofetch, a quick glance at the manifest of the Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS ISO (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.manifest) shows it there.. Your system as I see it is now Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (with LXDE), and I still have one IBM thinkpad using pentium M with 18.04 installed; but I'll likley move that to Debian within two months due to EOSS of 18.04 & EOL of *i386* (Debian & Ubuntu refer to all grades of 32-bit x86 as *i386*; your cpu will be *i686* class though to the linux kernel)

If you haven't worked it out, there is no upgrade path to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, as it was the last Ubuntu release that used the now *deprecated* LXDE desktop, with LXDE using the *deprecated* GTK2 libraries/toolkit. The LXDE *devs* wrote about the port of LXDE to GTK3 (*which is heavier*) and instead ported to Qt5 joining with the Razor-Qt *devs* creating the replacement LXQt desktop that Lubuntu from 18.10 & up uses.

Lubuntu 18.10 was released in *i386* (32-bit), with ISOs also produced of 19.04 (*Lubuntu & Xubuntu alone got this far*), but 19.04 was the end of the road for *i386* support & because 18.10/19.04 were not LTS releases, 18.04 LTS lived longer (3 years for *flavors* with EOSS or end of standard support at 5 years meaning April 2023).

From my own system, I'll get (using `neofetch`)

`````
           `-mddhhhhhhhhhddmss`             guiverc@d7050-next 
        ./mdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.         ------------------                                                                                       
     :mdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhm`       OS: Lubuntu Lunar Lobster (development branch) x86_64                                                    
   :ymhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhyyyyyyhhhhhhhhhy:      Host: OptiPlex 7050                                                                                      
  `odhyyyhhhhhhhhhy+-````./syhhhhhhhho`     Kernel: 6.1.0-16-generic                                                                                 
 `hhy..:oyhhhhhhhy-`:osso/..:/++oosyyyh`    Uptime: 2 mins                                                                                           
 dhhs   .-/syhhhhs`shhhhhhyyyyyyyyyyyyhs    Packages: 3057 (dpkg), 11 (snap)                                                                         
:hhhy`  yso/:+syhy/yhhhhhshhhhhhhhhhhhhh:   Shell: bash 5.2.15                                                                                       
hhhhho. +hhhys++oyyyhhhhh-yhhhhhhhhhhhhhs   Resolution: 1680x1050, 1920x1080, 1920x1080                                                              
hhhhhhs-`/syhhhhyssyyhhhh:-yhhhhhhhhhhhhh   DE: LXQt 1.2.0                                                                                           
hhhhhhs  `:/+ossyyhyyhhhhs -yhhhhhhhhhhhh   WM: Openbox                                                                                              
hhhhhhy/ `syyyssyyyyhhhhhh: :yhhhhhhhhhhs   Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK3]                                                                                 
:hhhhhhyo:-/osyhhhhhhhhhhho  ohhhhhhhhhh:   Icons: Yaru [GTK3]                                                                                       
 sdhhhhhhhyyssyyhhhhhhhhhhh+  +hhhhhhhhs    Terminal: qterminal                                                                                      
 `shhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy+` .yhhhhhhhh`    Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 14                                                                            
  +sdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhyo/. `/yhhhhhhhd`     CPU: Intel i5-6500 (4) @ 3.600GHz                                                                        
   `:shhhhhhhhhh+---..``.:+yyhhhhhhh:       GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530                                                                               
     `:mdhhhhhh/.syssyyyyhhhhhhhd:`         Memory: 1813MiB / 15852MiB                                                                               
        `+smdhhh+shhhhhhhhhhhhdm`                                                                                                                    
           `sNmdddhhhhhhhddm-`                                                                                                                       
                                                                    


guiverc@d7050-next:~$
`````

and what I consider the most important is actually

```
guiverc@d7050-next:~$   lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Lunar Lobster (development branch)
Release:        23.04
Codename:       lunar
```

You'll note the base system is reported as Ubuntu *lunar lobster*, what will be released next month as Lubuntu 23.04.

Comment: just to clarify.. my old laptop is 32 bit , are you saying that there is will be no more ubuntu/lubuntu supported version for 32 bit after apr 2023?  thx

Comment: @CoolPontiac Sadly, this is true - no version of Ubuntu will support 32-bit systems after April 2023, as Ubuntu dropped 32-bit support a while ago for all new releases. Ubuntu 18.04 is the last release to have 32-bit support, and it will become unsupported in about a month. You may want to consider switching to Debian with the LXDE desktop environment, as this will give you a very similar experience to Lubuntu 18.04, and Debian continues to support 32-bit systems for the time being.

Comment: FYI:  CoolPontiac myself & @ArrayBolt3 are both Lubuntu members (ie. *members of the Lubuntu team*).   Note: 32-bit is still supported if you're using an ARM processor (eg. *armhf* being the 32-bit Raspberry Pi type processor, *arm64* being the 64-bit Raspberry Pi type processor boards), but *i386* or 32-bit for x86 processor support ends in April 2023.  Extended support for 18.04 (beyond April 2023) is available for *supported architectures* which does **not** include *i386* it is my understanding.